# How to control (avoid) styling of nested html elements when using jQuery if classes are not an option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I am working on implementing a dynamic styling functionality in a Wordpress theme using jQuery. I am challenged by the fact that jQuery uses inline styling, which can have the effect that nested elements may get targeted by a selector even though that same selector has no effect in the CSS rules. To illustrate what I mean, please take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stefmldk/wx22zwbt/).

HTML:

```
<p>
  This is normal text
  <br>
  <br>
  <em>This is italic text</em>
  <br>
  <br>
  <strong>This is bold text</strong>
  <br>
  <br>
  <strong><em>This is bold italic text</em></strong>
  <br>
  <br>
  <em><strong>This is also bold italic text</strong></em>
  <br>
  <br>
</p>

<button>
  Style it!
</button>
```

CSS:

```
p em strong,
p strong em {
      color: red;
    }

p strong {
  color: blue;
}
```

jQuery:

```
(function($) {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('p strong').css('color', 'turquoise');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

As illustrated, CSS styling of the bold text only takes effect on the bold text as expected, but with jQuery - using the same selector, the instance of the bold italic text that has the  tag as a nested tag is also affected.

Is it possible to make a jQuery selection that does not include the nested elements as in the example? Obviously, if I could use classes, the solution would be simple, but I can't in this case.

If I add the !important option to the elements initially styled red, I get what i want, but I would really like to avoid that if at all possible. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking to solve a specific use case? Or this problem in general?

Comment: I think it covers both categories.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can exclude matches from a jQuery selection like `$('p strong').not('p em strong')` that would solve a specific use case.

Comment: But it doesn't solve the overall problem that jQuery is editing the style property of the element which adds an order of magnitude of specificity to the style.

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean. Actually, your example might be of use. I will look into this tomorrow and see if it can solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I added an answer with this info, as well as a way to solve the problem as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to solve a specific case, you can utilize the jQuery `.not()` method to exclude selections from a select. For this case:

```
$('p strong').not('p em strong').css('color', 'turquoise');
```

This doesn't solve the overall issue that jQuery `.css()` method edits the `style` attribute of the element, which adds an order of magnitude of specificity to a style when the browser determines which style to apply.

One alternative would be to create a JavaScript function that would add a new CSS style to the DOM. A sample function could look like:

```
var createCSSStyle = (function() {
    var styleSheet = null;
    return function(selector, cssOptions) {
        if (styleSheet == null) {
            styleSheet = document.createElement('style');
            styleSheet.type = 'text/css';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleSheet);
        }

        var text = " " + selector + " {";
        for(var prop in cssOptions)
            text += prop + ":" + cssOptions[prop] + ";";
        text += "}";

        styleSheet.innerHTML += text;
    };
})();
```

And to use it:

```
createCSSStyle('p  strong', { 'color' : 'turquoise' });
```

Here is an [update of your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx22zwbt/1/) with it in action.

Note: I used a self executing function here just so that I could have the style sheet saved to a local variable. I didn't want to create a new style sheet every time the method was called. Only the first time.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have played around with your solutions and found that filtering the jQuery objects becomes too messy when all potential use cases are considered. So I have chosen to go with your JavaScript function. I really like that styling behaves like normal CSS, which in this case means no surprises! I only changed the function slightly so that it recreates the CSS for each selector instead of appending to the existing styles. This is to allow the styling to fall back to a theme default instead of the last setting if a style is removed. Nice illustration of JavaScript closures as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood the problem you could use an immediate child selector.

```
$('p > strong').css('color', 'turquoise');
```

Comment: Thought about that as well, but I would like the styling to take effect everywhere, not just the immediate child, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will append a style tag to the head and then write the styles into it. Then you don't have inline styles.

```
(function($) {
   var styles = [];
   function styler(style){
      styles.push(style);
      $("#styler").html(styles.join("\n"));
   }
   $('button').on('click', function() {
      styler("p strong {color: turquoise;}")
   });

  $("head").append("<style id='styler'></style>")
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this selector `:nth-child` .?
Here is an example
https://jsfiddle.net/3pc98j7u/1/